# Can I use “as” to replace the “when”？

Tags: commas

“He alwas in St.Peter’s Square in Roma in 1978 WHEN John Paul II became Pope and in Tehran a year later WHEN the Shah fell.”
Can I use “as” to replace the “when”？

Answer (score 1):

It's more common to use *as* with an action. "He was fiddling as Rome burned" is fine; "He was in Tehran as Rome burned" is a little awkward. (That's in my American dialect. YMMV.) So I wouldn't use *as* in your sentence.

Also, use *was* in place of your *alwas*, and put a space between *St.* and *Peter's*.

Comment: 'As' is used with an ongoing process. You could say 'He was in Rome _as_ John Paul II _was being elected_ Pope' if you wanted to emphasize the idea of the crowd waiting for a result.